# images showing in designer but not the emulator

Tags: android

in my Design View it shows the two images on the screen, however on the emulator it doesn't show either of them, im brand new to this and have tried to make them visible to no avail, so any guidance in the right direction would be wonderful.

heres the Java for the program as im not sure if this useful? Line 16 is where i set the content view to that design page

The problem:

[image]

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView imageThumbnail;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cell_image_card);

    imageThumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

    imageThumbnail.setOnClickListener(itemClicked);
}

private View.OnClickListener itemClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //when the item is clicked, go ahead and open the new activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   };

   }
```

XML for the design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageTitle"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/singapore"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/starImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/shareImageBtn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainImage"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shareImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainImage"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded"
            tools:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

any guidance is appreciated as ive been trying for an hour to get this working

Comment: post your XML please

Comment: @elmorabea just added it, sorry

Comment: Why do you have a ConstraintLayout inside a CardView inside a ConstraintLayout? The outer ConstraintLayout is useless, just remove it. Remember to move the namespaces to the CardView tag

Comment: what are namespaces? sorry if its a stupid question. Im assuming the things like the images?

Comment: @AdamSteele (I think they're called namespaces, could be wrong though. Not extremely familiar with all the XML terms). But I'm referring to the `xmlns:app` and `xmlns:android` (and the tools one as well). Essentially all the declarations starting with `xmlns`. Those are important to get access to any of the calls you have used in the XML file

Comment: @Zoe still didn't seem to fix it unfortunately

Comment: @AdamSteele does it have constraints properly set up?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:src:imageName` instead of `app:srcCompat`....sometimes it works to change srcCompat to android:src...but don't ask me why...I had a project where changing was worth it